# CRMUD0082E Execution of a hook failed during the action New

Tags: c#, clearquest

I created a C# application (in VS2010) where am using CQAPI to create a new record in clearquest.
An exception is thrown at cqEntity.Validate()

> Error details: CRMUD0082E Execution of a hook failed during the action
>   New.  It was the ACTION_VALIDATION hook attached to the Defect.  The
>   reason for the failure was: Unknown exception executing
>   main::Defect_Validation.

Where, "Defect" indicates record name.
Am using CQ 8.0.0

Am I missing something? Could anyone please help?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

Validation seems to be failing for this record type according to what the schema designer intended, ask what the admin/developers of the CQ instance expect to see.

The error, comes from a custom script for the schema that tries to enforce validation, a so called Hook in CQ, which fails in a crash while trying to validate your record.